# How to i get array of items in properties with linq to entities?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Consider:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string[] WebSites{get;set;}
}
```

I have a query:

```
var allFoo=db.Persons.Select(p=>new Foo()
{
    Name=p.Name,
    WebSites=p.WebSites.Select(q=>q.Caption).ToArray(),
}).ToList();
```

But i get error " LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] ToArray... ".

How to i get All foo and websites string in a array with linq to entities?

Comment: could you show the definition of your Persons class, please?

Comment: Might be useful http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d53801f9-606e-4081-9360-b7efbaa93ad2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var allFooAnon = db.Persons.Select(p => new
{
  Name = p.Name,
  Websites = p.Websites.Select(q => q.Caption)
});

var list = new List<Foo>();
foreach (var anon in allFooAnon)
{
  list.Add(new Foo
  {
    Name = anon.Name,
    Websites = anon.Websites.ToArray()
  });
}
```

This creates a collection of anonymously-typed objects to hold the results of the query. You can then iterate over those objects to create your collection of `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

To use such methods like `ToArray` you might have to load all objects to memery by using `ToList`.

Answer (score -1):

Given your remark: But i get error " LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] ToArray..

I would suggest stripping the .ToArray() from

```
WebSites=p.WebSites.Select(q=>q.Caption).ToArray(),
```

Since apparently the result for

```
p.WebSites.Select(q=>q.Caption) is a System.String[]
```

This only means you will do an explicit cast from System.String[] to string[] which should be fine.

Comment: -1: `p.WebSites.Select(q=>q.Caption)` is of type `IEnumerable<string>`